# Xamarin Essentials Preferences and saving list

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to save values with Xamarin Essentials Preferences, however I am getting an exception as my  SavedList is always null and then as exception I have this Unhandled Exception:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 1, position 1. but I am only passing the string value to the saved list

```
private void ExecuteMultiPageCommand(bool value)
    {
      var recognitionProviderSettings = new RecognitionProviderSettings
        {SettingFields = new List<SettingField>()};

      var set = new SettingField()
      {
        ProviderSettingId = "test"
      
      };
  
       AddToList(set.ProviderSettingId);
       NotifyPropertyChanged("IsMultiPage");
    }
public static class Preference
  {
    public static List<string> SavedList
    {
      get
      {
        var savedList = Deserialize<List<string>>(Preferences.Get(nameof(SavedList), "test"));
        return savedList ?? new List<string>();
      }
      set
      {
        var serializedList = Serialize(value);
        Preferences.Set(nameof(SavedList), serializedList);
      }
    }

    static T Deserialize<T>(string serializedObject) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);

    static string Serialize<T>(T objectToSerialize) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);

  }

void AddToList(string text)
    {
      var savedList = new List<string>(Preference.SavedList) {text};


      Preference.SavedList = savedList;
    }
```

Comment: which **specific** line is causing the exception?  What is the stack trace for the exception?  And what **specific** value are you passing that causes the exception?

Comment: I am passing a string and the exception is at var savedList = Deserialize<List<string>>(Preferences.Get(nameof(SavedList), "test"));

Comment: what is the value being returned by `Preferences.Get(nameof(SavedList), "test")`?

Comment: I get null in saved list and then it fails in the exception I mentioned in my question

Comment: it should return the default value you provide, "test", if not saved value is found.  Have you tried deleting the app to erase any old test data might have been saved?

Comment: sorry my mistake I forgot to add  savedList.Add(text);